# Need Script for W10

Tags: windows, png

There is a folder with many subfolders.
Each subfolder has one .jpeg and another subfolder with .png

Script needs to delete the only .jpeg in that subfolder. 
Then take .png from the folder inside and delete the folder, but leave the .png.

I hope you understand what i am in need.
Please text me otherwise !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I lack of experience using scripts on windows. Do not want to somehow affect random files on work PC.

Comment: Well, SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
import shutil

previous_path = ""
previous = ("","")

for base, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\subDIRS"):
    if(len(files) != 0):
        if(os.path.isfile(previous[0] + "\\" + previous[1]) and
           os.path.splitext(files[0])[1].upper() == ".PNG" and
           os.path.splitext(previous[0] + "\\" + previous[1])[1].upper() == ".JPG"):

            shutil.move(base + "\\" + files[0], previous[0])
            os.removedirs(base)
            os.remove(previous[0] + "\\" + previous[1])
        previous = base, files[0]
```